# Array splice PHP and error in the documentation?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Take a look at this page with the documentation for `array_splice`, and inspect the first example.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

It is confusing me as the following code in example 1 is not correct as far as I can tell,

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 2);
// $input is now array("red", "green")
```

When I do this on my local machine I get the following,

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
array_splice($array, 10);
// $array is now array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
```

On PHPs page the example **returns** the elements, whereas on my local machine it **removes** them instead?

I don't get it? Am I missing something?

Comment: You've probably got `array_splice` on one and `array_slice` on the other.

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://codepad.org/QWejNaRY

Comment: Ah so I have, I am an idiot sometimes!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the documentation is wrong.

I tested your code and the code on php.net and works perfectly great, as in your example.

I am getting this:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 2);
// $input is now array("blue", "yellow")
```

So i would say that php.net is wrong (weird!! isn't it????)